# Integrating a customer feedback form with Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm attempting to implement a simple customer feedback system on my website and came across a couple of articles that used Google Analytics to collect feedback, which I've linked to below.

1./ [Push customer feedback results directly to Google Analytics with this new integration](https://mopinion.com/customer-feedback-google-analytics-integration/)

2./ [Using Google Analytics with Website Feedback](https://www.qualtrics.com/support/website-app-feedback/common-use-cases/using-google-analytics-with-website-feedback/)

I was wondering if this is a good practice? Is there any security risk, such as information exposure via query strings in URLs or web parameter tampering?

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to link to articles. It's pretty trivial and common implementation. What you can track in GA is limited. For example, in some countries you're not allowed to store PII (Personal identifiable information).  In other countries, they have GDPR, that has even more limitations.

And of course, getting data from GA to display it publicly is a bad idea too because GA was designed for internal use. Therefore, GA is a good solution if you can legally store that data on GA's servers and if you need it for personal analysis.

Comment: Since you mentioned GDPR, is it still legal to use GA to save feedback using localstorage rather than cookies to track the user if the end-user opts out of cookies?

Comment: I think it's more about storing their feedback on third-party servers. Local storage vs cookies makes no difference. Users aren't reasonably expected to know what cookies, local storage, web SQL or session storage are.